# How to change the label color of \psaxes?

Tags: color, pstricks, pst-plot

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-1)(5.5,5.5)
    \psaxes[linecolor=gray,tickcolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-5,-1)(5,5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to change the numeral label color of `\psaxes` from black (the default) to red (for example)?

Bonus question: Also how to change the color of the axis labels `x` and `y`? I have read the documentation at a glance but nothing can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the key `labelFontSize` to provide a generic formatting of the labels (*both* x and y):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-1)(5.5,5.5)
  \psaxes[linecolor=gray,tickcolor=gray,labelFontSize=\color{red}]{->}(0,0)(-5,-1)(5,5)%
    [\textcolor{blue}{$x$},0][\textcolor{green}{$y$},90]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand why there is no a semantically-correct key to change the color of `\psaxes` labels. `labelFontSize` key should be used just to change the size rather than the color.

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood: It's just a *hook* into that part of the algorithm. You could have named it `labelFont` to be a bit more general, implying that you can change anything about the font (color, size, shape, ...).

Answer (score 3):

Is the following what you are after?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
  \def\pst@@@hlabel#1{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}
  \def\pst@@@vlabel#1{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-1)(5.5,5.5)
  \psaxes[linecolor=gray,tickcolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-5,-1)(5,5)[\textcolor{gray}{$x$},0][\textcolor{gray}{$y$},90]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The result is what I want to achieve, but the method you used does not look as simple as `tickcolor=gray`. But of course +1 for your `\textcolor{gray}{$x$}`!

Comment: @CodeMocker I agree. `:)` (I found it on page 25 of the manual.)